# Local storage not shown after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just can't get it working no matter what I do. Been sitting for hours and nothing.  After submitting form I create local storage of values name, surname, email, so that I would be able to use them to fill up form so that user would not have to type them everytime. 
`submit()` is in review.controller.js

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('app').controller('ReviewController', ReviewController);

ReviewController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService', 'UniversalService', '$scope', '$sce', '$rootScope','$route','$cookies','localStorageService'];
function ReviewController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService, UniversalService, $scope, $sce, $rootScope,$route,$cookies,localStorageService) {
   var vm = this;
    vm.name = null;
    vm.surname = null;
    vm.Email = null;
    vm.review = null;
    vm.allgenres = [];
    vm.submit = submit;
    vm.allreviews = [];
    $scope.localArray=[];
    loadAllReviews();
    submit();

    $scope.templates = [{ name: 'man.main.view.html', url: 'main/main.view.html'}];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    function loadAllReviews() {      
        UniversalService.GetAllReviews()
            .then(function (review) {
                vm.allreviews = review;                    
            });
    }

    $scope.init = function () {debugger;
       // $scope.$MainController.obtained_array = localStorage.getItem("storageKey");debugger;
        $scope.storageKey = localStorage.getItem("storageKey");debugger;
    };

    $scope.storageKey = localStorage.getItem('storageKey');

  /*  $scope.$watch("storageKey", function() {debugger;
        localStorage.setItem('storageKey', storageKey); 
    });*/


    function submit() {  
    if($rootScope.name!=null)    {
        var JSONObject = {
             "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email,
             "review":$rootScope.review
            }
        var temp={
            "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email
        }
        $scope.localArray.push(temp);

        localStorageService.set("storageKey", $scope.localArray);

        $scope.storageKey = localStorageService.get("storageKey"); 
       // $rootScope.obtained_array = localStorageService.get("storageKey"); debugger;

        console.log($scope.storageKey);debugger;

        var Results = UniversalService.PostReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
        }
    }
}
```

main.controller.js

```
'use strict';
```

var app= angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

```
MainController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService', 'UniversalService', '$scope', '$sce', '$rootScope','$log','PagerService','localStorageService','$mdDialog'];
function MainController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService, UniversalService, $scope, $sce, $rootScope,$log,PagerService,localStorageService,$mdDialog) {
   var vm = this;
    vm.allreviews = [];
    vm.allusers=[];
    vm.allemails=[];
    vm.all=[];
    vm.avatars=[];
    $scope.filteredAll = [];
    $scope.all=[];
    $scope.items=[];

    $scope.pager = {};
    $scope.setPage = setPage;

    loadAllReviews();
    loadAllEmails();
    loadAllUsers();
    loadAll();
    loadAvatars();
    initController();
    setPage();
    submit();

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.$parent.storageKey = localStorage.getItem("storageKey");debugger;
       // $scope.obtained_array = localStorage.getItem("storageKey");
       // console.log(obtained_array); debugger;
       // $scope.storageKey = localStorage.getItem("storageKey");debugger;
    };


    function refresh() {
        location.reload();debugger;
    }


    function loadAll() {
        UniversalService.GetAll()
            .then(function (a) {
                $scope.all=a;
            });
    }

     function loadAllUsers(callback) {      
        UniversalService.GetAll()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.users=response;
                if (callback) {
                    callback(response);
                }
            });
    }

    function loadAllReviews() {      
        UniversalService.GetAllReviews()
            .then(function (review) {
                vm.allreviews = review;
            });
    }

    function loadAllEmails() {      
        UniversalService.GetAllEmails()
            .then(function (email) {
                vm.allemails = email;
            });
    }

    function setPage(page) {
        loadAllUsers(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                if (page < 1 || page > $scope.pager.totalPages) {
                    return;
            }
            // get pager object from service
            $scope.everything=response;
            $scope.pager = PagerService.GetPager(response.length, page);
            // get current page of items
            $scope.items = response.slice($scope.pager.startIndex, $scope.pager.endIndex + 1); 
            } 
        });
    }



    function initController() {
        $scope.setPage(1);  // initialize to page 1
    }
```

}

HTML file:

```
<div class="container padding-tb" id="Review">
<div ng-controller="ReviewController" ng-init="init()" ng-app id="Review">

<h2>Add review</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.submit()" role="form">
        <div >
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="name" onchange="CallItems()" id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.name" placeholder="Enter name here"  required />
                    <span ng-show="form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required" class="help-block">Name is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="surname" name="text" id="surname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.surname" placeholder="Enter surname here"  required/>
                    <span ng-show="form.surname.$dirty && form.surname.$error.required" class="help-block">Surname is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="Enter email here" required />
                    <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required" class="help-block">Email is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="review">Review</label>
                    <input type="text" name="text" id="review" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.review" placeholder="Enter review here"  required/>
                    <span ng-show="form.review.$dirty && form.review.$error.required" class="help-block">Review is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div class="form-actions">
                <button id="submit" type="submit" onclick="passInfo()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                <label style="display:none" id="label"><font color="white">Review succesfully created!  

                <a onclick="refresh()" href="../ang/#!/review">Add new review</a></label> or 
                <a href="../ang/#!/">View reviews!</a>


            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    <div>

        <div ng-init="init()" class="slide-animate-container">
        <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="main.view.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I add these values to button to test if values are added:

`<button ng-disabled="localStorage.getItem('LS_wimmtkey') !== null"> {{obtained_array}}</button>`

My main.view is inserted into the review.view (because form and reviews are on the same page, main is for the review listing and reviews are submitted form)

After submiting form all these values appear in the button, but after refreshing page none of them are shown anymore. I kind of understand that it is all because everything I do with local storage is inside `submit()` function, but I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: After refresh how are you populating $rootScope values?

Comment: In another controller I have this line: ` $rootScope.obtained_array = localStorage.getItem("LS_wimmtkey");` but that doesn't seem to help

Comment: can you also post other controller code

Comment: please check whether the data is stored in the localstorage or not

Comment: Yes it is stored

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `init` function on second controller and set the local Storage value in a variable.So whenever you refresh the page, `init` function will be called and local storage value will be available for you to use it in View

Comment: `$scope.init = function () {
            $rootScope.obtained_array = localStorage.getItem("LS_wimmtkey");debugger;
    };` I wrote this and in my view I call it ` <div class="review-container" ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="init()">` and after submit it has values, but after refresh `obtained_array` in init() is null

Answer (score 0):

see below line:

```
<button ng-disabled="localStorage.getItem('LS_wimmtkey') !== null"> {{obtained_array}}</button>
```

"obtained_array" belong to $rootScope, so $rootScope can't bind to the template(binding to $rootScope is not possible )

quick solution is: change the following line
in case of: **MainController**

```
$scope.obtained_array = localStorage.getItem("LS_wimmtkey");debugger;
```

in case of :**ReviewController** (you are setting in this ctrl "LS_wimmtkey")

```
$scope.$parent.obtained_array = localStorage.getItem("LS_wimmtkey");debugger;
```